# Does 32-bit Windows 7 Home Premium automatically support PAE?

Tags: windows-7, memory

Does 32-bit Windows 7 Home Premium automatically support PAE, for accessible RAM larger than 4GB? Or do I have to manually do some change?

Comment: Also it's better to just use 64-bit Windows.

Answer (score 2):

[No variant of 32-bit Windows 7 supports more than 4GB regardless](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366778%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#physical_memory_limits_windows_7), so whether or not PAE is enabled is irrelevant.

Comment: http://prasys.info/2012/05/enabling-more-than-4gb-ram-on-windows-7-32-bit/ http://www.raymond.cc/blog/make-windows-7-and-vista-32-bit-x86-support-more-than-4gb-memory/ - just something I've read about before

Comment: @ekaj: Those do a lot more than just "enable PAE". They *replace key components of Windows itself*, changing how it behaves at a low level.

Comment: I was thinking about the manually change part of the question

Comment: @ekaj: But simply enabling PAE won't let you access more than 4GB, due to that low level behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the maximum amount of addressable memory, for **all** version of Microsoft Windows, including the Server editions, [at this Wikipedia Web page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_Address_Extension#Microsoft_Windows): The most important part is the following table:

> ### Windows Version [13]    32-bit editions 64-bit editions
>
> Windows 2000 Professional, Server 4 GB    N/A
>
> Windows 2000 Advanced Server  8 GB    N/A
>
> Windows 2000 Datacenter   32 GB   N/A
>
> Windows XP Starter    512 MB  N/A
>
> Windows XP Home & Media Center    4 GB    N/A
>
> Windows XP Professional   4 GB    128 GB
>
> Windows Server 2003 Web   2 GB    N/A
>
> Windows Server 2003 Small Business, Home, Storage 4 GB    N/A
>
> Windows Server 2003 Storage Server    4 GB    N/A
>
> Windows Server 2003 R2 Standard Edition   4 GB    32 GB
>
> Windows Server 2003 Standard Edition (SP1)    4 GB    32 GB
>
> Windows Server 2003 Standard Edition (SP2)    4 GB    32 GB
>
> Windows Server 2003 Enterprise Edition (SP1)  16 GB with 4GT  N/A
>
> Windows Server 2003 R2 Enterprise Edition 64 GB   1 TB
>
> Windows Server 2003 Datacenter (SP1)  128 GB  N/A
>
> Windows Server 2003 R2 Datacenter (SP1)   128 GB  1 TB
>
> Windows Server 2003 R2 Datacenter (SP2)   128 GB  2 TB
>
> Windows Vista Starter 1 GB    N/A
>
> Windows Vista Home Basic  4 GB    8 GB
>
> Windows Vista Home Premium    4 GB    16 GB
>
> Windows Vista Business, Enterprise, Ultimate  4 GB    128 GB
>
> Windows Server 2008 Standard, Web 4 GB    32 GB
>
> Windows Server 2008 Enterprise, Datacenter    64 GB   2 TB
>
> Windows 7 Starter 2 GB    N/A
>
> Windows 7 Home Basic  4 GB    8 GB
>
> Windows 7 Home Premium    4 GB    16 GB
>
> Windows 7 Professional, Enterprise, Ultimate  4 GB    192 GB
>
> Windows 8 4 GB    128 GB
>
> Windows 8 Pro 4 GB    512 GB

From this you can see that, if you have a *32-bit* Windows (not just
Windows 7) it is **always** limited to *4GB*, unless you are using a
Windows Server Edition.